# What does "CODE(0x1431a90)" mean when the Perl debugger outputs this for $DB::sub?

Tags: perl, debugging

I have a question about the output that I'm getting from a simple custom Perl debugger.

If I have a simple Perl debugger like this example:

```
package DB 
{
  sub DB {}

  sub sub
  { 
    my ($package, $filename, $line_num, $subroutine, $hasargs,
    $wantarray, $evaltext, $is_require, $hints, $bitmask, $hinthash) = caller(0);

    print "$package $DB::sub\n";

    &$DB::sub;
  }
}

1;
```

And I run it on a simple program like the following (invoked via `perl -d test.pl`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub hello
{
    print "hello world\n";
}

&hello;
```

And the output is along the lines of the following:

```
main CODE(0x1431a90)
main strict::import
main strict::bits
main CODE(0x1431be0)
main warnings::import
 main::hello
hello world
```

My question is:

What does the "CODE(0x1431a90)" part represent?  It seems to represent the main body of the program - since there is no subroutine at the topmost level, this seems to be a memory reference to the main execution of the program.

What assumptions can I make about what "CODE(...)" means when I see it being printed out by my debugger?  Is it always this "main" code path?  Are there any other special Perl variables that I can use to interpret where the program is at that point?

Thanks!

---

EDIT - revised example 1:

In reference to the discussion in the comments, adding additional example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub hello
{
    print "hello world\n";
}

&hello;

print "hi from main\n";
```

And output:

```
main CODE(0x22f0a90)
main strict::import
main strict::bits
main CODE(0x22f0be0)
main warnings::import
 main::hello
hello world
hi from main
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a code reference, and probably an anonymous one. See the `coderef2text` method in [`B::Deparse`](http://metacpan.org/pod/B%3a%3aDeparse) to get at (an approximation of) the actual source code, and display the file and linenumber (which you are already extracting from `caller`) to find where the sub is called from.

---

Running `B::Deparse::coderef2text` on your sample script, the code references resolve to

```
require strict;
do {
    'strict'->import
};
```

and

```
use strict 'refs';
require warnings;
do {
    'warnings'->import
};
```

meaning they are generated and called by `perl` from your `use strict` and `use warnings` statement.

Answer (score 2):

`CODE(0x1431a90)` is stringification of code reference.

Comment: Thanks. So those code refs seem to line up with `use strict;` and `use warnings;` - are they code refs because the calling lines in main aren't in subroutines?  But if that's the case, then in the revised example that I just added, why does `hi from main` show up without a code ref? Thanks!